# Relative rendering of objects from one mobile screen to another when taking into account 'device-width' & physical screen sizes

Tags: android, ios, css, iphone, responsive-design

Im just about to publish some research on '**pixel rendering within the browser, specifically on mobile devices**'. My research is based around the relative rendering of objects from one mobile screen to another when taking into account 'device-width' & physical screen sizes. I produced this over a year ago, but to date have never released it.

**2 Questions:**

1. Have you guys seen anything on this that speaks specifically about
   'relative rendering of objects from one mobile screen to another
   when taking into account 'device-width' & physical screen sizes'
   (Sorry to be asking this, but most of my research to see if anyone
   else has covered this doesn't seem to specifically mention 'the
   browser' and more the hardware PPI of the screen.
2. Does the returned value of 'resolution' media query return the screen PPI or the effective browser PPI once 'device-width' has been taken into account.

Sorry if these are dumb questions, im actually a designer with a knowledge of coding, but their are wholes in my knowledge from being self taught.

Thanks

Matt